# What is a safe way to carry around (wrt ESD safety) a single-board computer in an enclosure like this?

Tags: pcb, esd, discharge, sbc, electrostatic

I have a single-board computer and an enclosure, which will hopefully look like this in the end:

[image: Acrylic enclosure for UDOO x86]

I have three small questions:

- If I only hold it from the edges while assembling the enclosure, do I risk ESD damage?
- While the acrylic enclosure is on, will it be ok to carry it around by holding it from the casing?
- What kind of additional protection should I use if I want to carry it around, e.g. in a bag (should I put it in some kind of box)?

Comment: These are all too broad questions. Holding it from the edges is likely to be fine, except if you are in a very dry environment for example. So the answer is, depends. Same for holding it from the casing: ESD can arc. I've never had any problems carrying my boards around in my backpack, but that doesn't mean its ESD safe. You can use a cardboard box with some conductive foam to prevent the board from dragging inside it. Still, you are gonna have to handle it eventually so.. too many scenarios.

Comment: I agree with @WesleyLee ; it's generally safe but ironicallly acrylic is a pretty good ESD generator.

Comment: @pjc50 Apparently acrylic panels are available with a dissipative film on them, e.g. [ESD acrylic panels](http://www.linkhamson.com/Products/Equipment/esd-solutions/various-esd/esd-acrylic-panels) (I haven't used it).

Comment: @WesleyLee Yes, I am afraid they are very broad, indeed, but I am quite confused about the matter, imagine that I initially thought I would get away with carrying the naked board around... So, it seems that a completely closed enclosure would probably be much better, I just couldn't find one yet. Anyway, I think I will be holding it as close to the edges of the casing as possible. Thank you people. I guess I will also have to take care not to touch those exposed pins, right?

Comment: I personally worry more about how and where I move (i.e.: am I working in a room with carpeted floors, is the environment dry, try to discharge myself (and/or the board) to something before touching it, etc) than if I touch a pin or not (ofc I try to not hold the things by the pins but I think you get my point).

Comment: A metal case is likely to be more suitable for moving it around a lot, and may provide better ESD protection. Although the small fan that's then required might be annoying.

Comment: @WesleyLee how can I safely discharge the board? Touch it to ground? Also, would it be any helpful to carry this enclosed SBC around in an antistatic or static-shielding bag?

Comment: Touching it to "ground" will discharge it, but too fast :) In that sense, ESD foams and bags are nice, they are conductive so it allows the board to stay generally in the same charge level as the environment, but not so conductive that a discharge would be too fast.

Comment: Touch the GND region of the PCB, or touch the GND pins of the power connectors. Then touch the inside of the metal pan you will use to transport the Computer. Then place the Computer inside the pan.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, interesting... I assume I have to touch the inside of the metal pan **while** touching the GND region of the PCB, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an ESD aficionado so take the following under advisement only. 
 Seriously though, I wouldn't call your two sheets of acrylic an enclosure for the simple reason that it doesn't actually enclose. It's one sheet on top and another beneath.

I would consider this to be one of the worst arrangements for ESD possible.  You have two charge carriers sandwiching the very item you wish to protect. Have a quick look at [this](http://resources.schoolscience.co.uk/PPARC/11-14/partch3pg3.html) childish but useful cartoon illustrating static build up with acrylic rods.  Static charge in itself is not a problem.  Birds take 400kV sitting on distribution cables without even noticing.  The problems begin when they try to step off onto a grounded metal ladder. It's potential induced current that can damage circuitry and fowl, as in touching the pcb to one of the acrylic panels and perhaps the other.  If one panel is at 10kV because it rubbed on the silk hanky in your bag, and the other is at 5kV, that leaves the other 5kV to flow through your GPIO pin.  Zap. Grr.

It's not sexy or the Zeitgeist, but I do what the military do. Cover it in metal. Use a full metal box with fitted lid.  Small openings for the connector ports and try to get a low resistance path from the grounds to the box.  Aluminium or die cast zinc are the most machinable by hobbyists.  That way any accumulated static charge on the enclosure cannot flow though the computer itself. It will perform a [Faraday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) shield effect around the board protecting it like an air plane is protected from lightning strikes.

A side benefit is the thermal transmittance of metal.  Your heat sink is not huge. You could expose it carefully through a tightly fitting hole, but you could just completely enclose it and rely on passive transmission through the entire case walls. There are [Raspberry Pi enclosures](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=169107) that rely on this cooling method although the Pi is     a   bit less power hungry.

Crazily, you could also just wrap it up in tin foil for infrequent transport.  Just make sure that you touch something grounded before wrapping it like a radiator or the screws on a PC. If you're concerned about ESD whilst assembling it (perhaps justified due to the acrylic), you could use an earthed wrist band like:-

[image: wrist band]

Comment: So, it would be more important, if using an insulating material for enclosure, to keep a relatively safe distance from the material. The truth is that I also initially thought that this "sandwich" arrangement is a bit awkward and unsafe for a PCB. Then, again, I watched this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fy7dTBN_yCg) and noticed that the people of the "_official_" guide actually wear anti-static wrist bands **with no cord**. In any case (pun not intended), I think [this](https://i.imgur.com/wEdclSS.jpg) will be more suitable, right?

Comment: @ForeverNoob That case certainly looks more suitable. Note that you'll want to put a wire fan guard on the fan (they are only a dollar or so).

Comment: @AndrewMorton something like [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/GNIAAOSwbYZXa7lm/s-l1600.jpg), for example?

Comment: @ForeverNoob Yes, one like that. Make sure it's for a 40mm fan. Your fingers will thank you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is actually a 30mm fan (if I didn't miss anything), it's the intel pentium N3710 CPU.

Comment: @ForeverNoob Are you referring to the guy with the green band on his right wrist?  That's a rubber band /bracelet over a friendship band methinks.  The cord is mandatory for the anti-static band's effect. Otherwise how does the static dissipate?

Comment: @PaulUszak It doesn't (supposedly through the air, but these things are definitively bogus). You might be right, but I am very much afraid that wireless such stuff are widely used all around, in just the last two days, I met at leats two technicians working with these on... I am slightly confused about one thing, if the guy in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBUXpMq06iU) is not grounded (I cannot be certain that they are, but they are working on a wooden board anyway), then how realistic is it that the device will survive such handling? Isn't this too dangerous for such a device?

Comment: @ForeverNoob So it is - [CPU fan for UDOO X86 heatsink](https://shop.udoo.org/eu/catalog/product/view/id/62/s/cpu-fan-for-udoo-x86-heatsink/category/3/). Make sure it's a 30 mm one then :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton sure! My problem is that I cannot find how to ground the board to the metal case (I am completely unsure as to how to do that). As Paul Uszak stated in the answer "Small openings for the connector ports and try to get a low resistance path from the grounds to the box". What are the "grounds" and why should I do that? I am completely clueless and the [schematics](http://download.udoo.org/files/UDOO_X86/schematics/UDOOX86_revH_schematics.pdf) don't really mean something to me, unfortunately. Or did Paul Uszak mean the true ground rather than the pcb ground?

Comment: @ForeverNoob Wire from PCB's entry of 0V or GND (what ever you have) to the case.  Look up star grounding to avoid pesky loops.  Shameless beg for upvote :-)

Comment: The schematics show up tons of GND actually, although I can visually recognize one pin that clearly has GND written next to it. I understand there is one "main" (whatever that means) GND, that must be it, right? And how does this shield the board from static? Does it redirect the discharge somehow? (Sorry for asking too much, I am trying to understand the physics of it at the same time).

Comment: @PaulUszak I have upvoted all along, but, unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation for the upvote to show up.